# Finding WGL with MinGW

Tags: windows, opengl, mingw, wgl

I've wrote an adequate little program in C that creates a window. However, I'm having trouble adding the OpenGL rendering context and assorted functions to it.

GetDC, ChoosePixelFormat, SetPixelFormat -- all wgl functions, as I understand it. I thought these may be specific to Visual C++, but this does not seem to be the case -- unless they've been radically altered to be C++ only; the amount of errors, compared to MinGW, is stunning.

Where can I find WGL?
How can I add it to MinGW?

(Slightly related sourcecode can be found here: http://pastebin.com/eMWLqL6h )

Comment: Perhaps the inclusion of wingdi.h will lead to positive results. As I understood, it was supposed to be included by (and apart of) windows.h.

Comment: Fixed. Will post the answer in 7 hours, unless some kind soul beats me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing the following libraries into MinGW/lib resolved all issues:

win32api
wing32
GDI
GDI32
GDIPLUS
OpenGL
opengl32

These are called in order by gcc. No longer are there undefined or contradictory define errors.

Headers then need only be:
GL/gl.h
windows.h

Comment: Can you please describe how you downloaded and installed, for example win32api, for MinGW, I am having a very hard time finding a information on this.  Thanks.